# Collaborative Vulnerability Assessment / Penetration Test Tool Suggestions

Tags: security, collaboration, information-management

I am in the process of evaluating [Infobyte's Faraday tool](http://www.infobytesec.com/faraday.html) and putting it into use for pentesting and collaboration with my colleagues. The idea is great but the app seems to be in the early stages of development and testing. I would like to consider alternatives, the ideal tool featuring:

- Multi-user, central access to vulnerability assessment / pentesting results
- Web based interface preferred (client access via browser), not essential
- Import and manage data from popular infosec tools
- Customisable web-based dashboard for colleagues, clients
- Client report document generation, editable

Any suggestions / experience with alternative packages would be appreciated.